# Cannot generate synthetic image samples data from Docker Isaac sim Object Detection Training

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, nvidia, data-generation

Creating data folder /workspace/tlt-experiments/data WARNING: flashing images!! ***** Don’t visit the following URL if you are sensitive to flashing lights ******* Go to http://localhost:3000 see the generated images being generated
Generated 0 samples
Generated 0 samples
Generated 0 samples
Generated 0 samples
Generated 0 samples

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur in Isaac 20 and 21, the start.sh script expect version to be 19. So, We need to modify the start.sh file. Need to comment below lines

Modify the start.sh like this

```
#if [[ $IS_19 == 1 ]]; then
NV_FLAG="--gpus=all"
#else
#    NV_FLAG="--runtime=nvidia -e CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all"
#fi
```

and keep only NV_FLAG="--gpus=all".